# Getting error ": command not found" when trying to run shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a script that I'm trying to run but I just get the error ": command not found" whenever I try to run it. Here's what I've tried to do to fix it:

1. Made sure the hashbang is correct "#!/bin/bash"
2. Run dos2unix on the file
3. Run the script as scriptname.sh, ./scriptname.sh, and /bin/bash scriptname.sh
4. chmod 755 scriptname.sh

I still am unable to run the script.

Comment: 5. Show the script? ;)

Comment: Does anything appear before your colon? Something like, `-bash: not_a_real_command: command not found`?

Comment: @chrisaycock nothing before the colon. That's why I was really confused.

also, i'm a little iffy about posting the code of the script, but I swear it was working before I committed it to a repo and then synced it again

Comment: Could you copy and paste your entire shell session? In particular, `cat` your script, `ls -l` it, and then run it. Just modify your question to paste all of the text from your console.

Comment: When you run `./scriptname.sh` the error is 'command not found' (and not 'no such file or directory')?

Comment: Sounds like step 2 didn't take...

Comment: that is correct @ArnonZilca. I was hoping there might be a general checklist of things to try. But I guess not...

Comment: Pipe the error message through `cat -A` or `cat -v`: `./scriptname.sh 2>&1 | cat -A`

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Turns out I called when I called "source env.rc" in the script it failed because env.rc also acquired dos line endings when I pulled it from the repo. Sorry to waste everyone's time with a stupid error. The error message wasn't particularly helpful tho

Comment: @Erik I'll take that as a lesson. Nice one you solved it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is caused by carriage returns. Here's the excerpt from the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info):

1. **Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters**

   - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v` .

     DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.

     If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`

Make sure to check all your data, and not just the script itself.

Comment: From the question it sounds like he just ran dos2unix on the file.

Comment: Because of the check all data statement, I'll accept your answer

Comment: I have same problem but no DOS carriage returns found

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to delete unnecessary characters:

```
tr -cd '[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]\n' < script.sh > new_script.sh
```

Or

```
tr -cd '[:graph:][:blank:]\n' < script.sh > new_script.sh
```

Then try `new_script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have extra whitespaces.
It happened to me when I tried to assign a value to a variable:
`a = "test"` instead of `a="test"`