# MacOS: Bizarre behavior with .bashrc; doesn't run comments, seems to be dropping characters in parse

Tags: bash, git, macos, shell

This is an odd one to try to describe, so it is probably better to show. I have this content in my `.bashrc` file on MacOS, which gets called from `.bash_profile`:

```sh
# .bashrc

export VENV_HOME=~/.venvs
export VENV_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7

source ~/skel/bashrc-include-base.sh
source ~/skel/bashrc-include-linux.sh
source ~/skel/bashrc-include-django.sh
source ~/skel/bashrc-include-git.sh
source ~/skel/venv-wrapper.sh

unalias ls
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

Nothing too exotic. But when I fire up Terminal, or try to `source .bashrc` or `. .bashrc`, it doesn't run and gives the following errors:

```sh
My-MacBook:~ me$ source .bashrc
: command not found
: command not found
: No such file or directoryashrc-include-base.sh
: No such file or directoryashrc-include-linux.sh
: No such file or directoryashrc-include-django.sh
: No such file or directoryashrc-include-git.sh
: No such file or directoryenv-wrapper.sh
: command not found
: not foundias: ls
```

I've checked my terminal (which is `xterm-256color`). I've made sure neither `source` nor `.` is an alias:

```sh
My-MacBook:~ me$ type source
source is a shell builtin
My-MacBook:~ me$ type .
. is a shell builtin
```

Here's what is even more bizarre: if I create a new file and add the same contents, it runs just fine. If I copy that file over `.bashrc`, it runs just fine. But I keep this file in version control, and `git` doesn't see any difference. Any idea what would cause this behavior?

Comment: I'd bet each of those lines ends with a carriage-return, which is treated as part of the command (or file name).

Comment: It sounds like the same problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252573/getting-error-command-not-found-when-trying-to-run-shell-script)—the error you are seeing occurs if the file uses carriage returns.

Comment: Note, by the way, that some Unix editors, in a (misguided?) attempt to be "friendly" with DOS/Windows-sourced files, will remove all the `\r` endings when reading the file, let you edit it without ever knowing it had `\r` endings, then *put all the `\r` endings back* when you write out the file.

Comment: Thanks y'all. Yeah, it was line endings, as suspected.